# efficient function call

Tags: c

I need your help in writing a efficient program.

I have approx 50 functions say `call_1()`, `call_2()` ... `call_50()`. I need to call them based on the index read from a data packet, i.e if the field in data is 25 in need to call `call_25()`, if 10 then `call_10()`.

I have written this in if else condition like

```
if (index == 5) 
    call_5() 
elseif (index == 6)
   ..so on ..
```

But I think this is not the efficient way of writing. Any other ideas of implementing this scenario?
Can function pointers help here? 
Appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: Plenty of good answers telling you how to create the function pointer table and call into it. Just don't forget to check your input to ensure your call is actually based on your initialized table, and not off the end of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use a lookup table of function pointers:

```
typedef void(*fp)(void);

void call_01(void);
void call_02(void);
/* ... */

fp functions[] = { &call_01,
                   &call_02,
                   /* ... */
                 };

void call()
{
    unsigned int n = get_index();
    functions[n]();
}
```

Comment: The & is not necessary in the table assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If the arguments are same for all 50 functions, use an array of function pointers:

```
typedef void (*FieldHandler)(void);

const FieldHandler handlers[50] = { call_0, call_1, /* ... and so on ... */ };
```

Then you just index into the array and call:

```
handlers[index]();
```

Comment: if the arguments in the functions are not same, this approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of function pointers there easily, if all your functions have the same signature.

```
typedef void (*func)(void);
...
func dispatch_table[] = {
   func0,
   func1,
   func2,
...
   func50,
};
```

And later use like this

```
int function_index = packet_get_func_index( packet );
...
dispatch_table[ function_index ]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, function pointers are the way to go here.

I would suggest creating a table of function pointers and since your input is an index, you just index into the table to call the right function.

Comment: But what If have functions with different arguements.. will still work?? if not then what is the best procedure. please clarify..

Comment: If your functions do not have the same signature (arrangement of arguments and return type) then using function pointers is problematic. It would be best to change how your functions are organized to make them compatible but if this is not an option, your choices are a switch table (as @lucas clemente demonstrates), an ugly series of if statements, or creating a series of pre-functions which have the same arguments, where each calls another function with its proper (and potentially different) arguments.

Comment: Thanks for you reply/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a switch statement:

```
switch(index) {
  case 1: return call01();
  case 2: return call02();
  case 3: return call03();
}
```

This is not a lot more code than using function pointers, and it's (imho) more concise.

Comment: This would only be appropriate if the input (index) was sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is pretty inefficient.  I think the best way to proceed is to write a dispatcher of this form in the range of 0 - 255:

void (*dispatcher[255]);

Of course, you would need to assign all the necessary functions instead of doing the if statements, but this would be a heck of a lot faster:

```
dispatcher['a'] = &call_1;
dispatcher['b'] = &call_2;
dispatcher['c'] = &call_3;
...
```

Then you can just do:

dispatcher(index) and it would know which function to execute.

Hope that helps.